# Minitoc vertical spacing

Tags: minitoc

I want to adjust the vertical spacing between minitoc title and the top horizontal rule? This is for bottom hrule

```
\renewcommand{\kernafterminitoc}{\kern-0.1\baselineskip\kern0.1ex}
```

I used

```
mtcsetfeature{minitoc}{open}{\vspace{0.5cm}}
```

which adjusts the vertical spacing between the top horizontal rule and the contents and not between the title and top rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally solved it just have to add `\par` in minitoc title

```
\mtcsettitle{minitco}{Contents of Chapter \par}
```

and you got it.

Comment: Correct your question: add "\" at "mtcsettitle" after "I used" and at your answer correct "minitco" with "minitoc". Best Regards